# Rails simple_form not highlighting fields with errors in red

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I am using simple_form in my rails 5 application, but fields with errors are not highlighted in red, and neither are the error messages. All I get is an error box at the top of the form with a message "Please review the problems below:" but the fields with errors are not in red. I have searched everywhere but I can't seem to get a solution. Here is my code for the form:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<%= simple_form_for @staff do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <%= f.input :Title, collection: ["Mr", "Ms", "Mrs", "Dr", "Prof"] %>
  <%= f.input :FirstName, label: 'First Name' %>
  <%= f.input :OtherNames, label: 'Other Names' %>
  <%= f.input :Surname %>
  <%= f.input :DisabilityType, label: 'Disability Type', collection: 
 ["Albinism", "Learning", "Mental", "Physical-Hearing", "Physical-Visual", 
  "Physical-Psycomotor", "Other"] %>
  <%= f.input :NationalID, label: 'National ID' %>
 <div class = "form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>

    </div>
<% end %>
</div></div>
```

What could I be doing wrong? I am creating an app as I read the rails tutorial by Hartl.

Thanks.

Comment: Make all the keys lowercase. `f.input :title`

Comment: If I do that I get a `NoMethodError`, since that's how the fields are named in the migrations

Comment: Still an issue with rails 7.1 and simple_form - if you have a solution please share.